# Cannot write value to specific Cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

New to Python. I am trying to store input value to specific cell.
stockleft needs to be stored on the row where 'BARCODE' = barcode (user input barcode), Column ='STOCK'...
What am i doing wrong???

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ufo = pd.read_excel('items.xlsx')
wb = load_workbook('items.xlsx')
ws= wb.active
#Columns ='BARCODE','DESCRIPTION','STOCK']

barcode=input("Enter Barcode: ")
stockleft=input("Enter How many are Left: ....")
ws[ufo.loc[ufo['BARCODE'] == barcode ,'STOCK']].value=stockleft #attempt1
#ufo.loc[ufo['BARCODE']==barcode, 'STOCK'] =stockleft #attempt2
wb.save('items.xlsx')
```

Comment: Why are you reading the same file twice, and what does the function `load_workbook` do? Try using only the ufo `dataframe` throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempt 2 syntax seems right, it will update the dataframe. The stockleft should be integer and save the same dataframe to excel using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ufo = pd.read_excel('items.xlsx')
#Columns ='BARCODE','DESCRIPTION','STOCK']

barcode = input("Enter Barcode: ")
stockleft = int(input("Enter How many are Left: ...."))
ufo.loc[ufo['BARCODE']==barcode, 'STOCK'] = stockleft #attempt2

ufo.to_excel('items_modified.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts...
ufo.to_excel ('items.xlsx')
that was the issue with my code!!

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt 2 looks correct, but you are applying it to `ufo` while you are saving `wb`. So if you are just looking at the output file you won't see any change, you must save the dataframe `ufo` instead.